# kernel boot messages are not seen after removing quiet boot parameter

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, bootloader

I have removed kernel boot parameter "quiet" in my boot loader config file. My boot loader config file looks like  `vga=791 rw root=/dev/ram0 loglevel=0 pci=pcie_scan_all,realloc` . But during the kernel loading boot messages are not displayed on the screen. After booting verified the kernel command line parameters in /proc/cmdline and it is showing as  `BOOT_IMAGE=dev000:\EFI\BOOT\linux vga=791 rw root=/dev/ram0 loglevel=0 pci=pcie_scan_all,realloc` . Do I need to configure any other parameter to display the kernel boot messages on the screen.

Comment: `quiet` is equivalent to `loglevel=4`, which I think was overriding your `loglevel=0` parameter. When you removed `quiet`, then you essentially forced `loglevel` to 0. Try changing `loglevel` to 4 in your boot parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove loglevel=0 option from the bootargs. This option will only print emergency messages during kernel boot. Try with some other loglevels (0-7) for print options.

Loglevel  0 :
KERN_EMERG |    "0" | Emergency messages, system is about to crash or is unstable | pr_emerg

[Click here for Detailed loglevel options](http://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing#Log_Levels)

Comment: I have the same issue as OP, but removing quiet and/or loglevel doesn't help, nor does loglevel=7.